# Wrong order during eval of array content with ZSH

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

Considering the following example script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
typeset -A cmd 

cmd[0]="mkdir"
cmd[1]="-p"
cmd[2]="to to/tata"
cmd[3]="anotherfolder"
```

I'm trying to eval the content of cmd (and keep the parameter separation, so I want to create "to to/tata" and "anotherfolder") but when I do:

> ${cmd}

It evals the content, but in the wrong order. For some reason it evals:

> anotherfolder mkdir -p "to to/tata"

Do you have any idea why, and how to make it follow the natural order?

---

If you want to know what I'm really trying to do (because there might be a simpler way to do what I want), I created a small shell script that takes a command as argument, and executes it one specific folders. For exemple:

> myscript mkdir -p "to to/tata"

And in my script, I simply have:

```
$@
```

That executes the mkdir command. But now, I'm trying to pass multiple command using a specific separator ("--" in my case) so that

> myscript mkdir -p "to to/tata" -- touch "to to/tata/myfile"

would execute both commands. To do so, I thought it would be easier to first parse $@ and create arrays containing each arguments up to "--". But now I'm stuck on how to execute the array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I used an associative array (typedef -A) instead of a standard array.

Proper solution would be:

```
cmd=()
# indexes start at 1
cmd[1]="mkdir"
cmd[2]="-p"
```